# Facebook PHP Api, can't get email

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a Facebook login for my web app, but i am stuck retrieving the logged profile email. I've tried using different account for testing purpose, but none of them is able to return the profile email, and all the profile have a valid email registered on Facebook. When I get redirected to the Facebook login page, the box ask to share the email address correctly, but i'm still not getting the email!

Here getting the login url

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = array('email', 'user_likes');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('url', $permissions);
```

Here the callback code:

```
$APPID = 'appid';
$APPSecret = 'appsecret';
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $APPID,
    'app_secret' => $APPSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
if($accessToken){
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email');
    $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    var_dump($userNode);
    echo $userNode->getProperty('email');
}
```

The result:

```
object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser)#66 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(15) "........" } }
```

using this code i'm able to get only the id of the user or the name, removing `?fieds=email` from the requesting url

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Some times, Facebook don't send back the email of the user. It appends when an email is not verified by the user. When it happen you can show a form just for the email.

Comment: my email is verified but still not sended

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all the emails from a page ??
or the email of the person who is using your application ??

Comment: the email of the person who is using the application

Comment: then i think that should not be the problem as whoever will login using your application ,you can use his email if you have got the rights. Have you submitted your app and is searchable ??

Answer (score 0):

Change ***/me?fields=email*** to ***/{user-id}?fields=email***

or

check your permission include correct or not

UPDATE 1:

your request url like doing that

*https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{user-id}?fields=email&access_token={access-token}*